# could not get the desired output in MPPT

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega, adc

I am trying to program an MPPT solar charge controller for a constant output to charge the connected tubular battery. I have used an ADC pin to get the output voltage through feedback and generate the PWM signal accordingly.
From another GPIO pin(PINC6), it drives the transistor that it turn would turn MOSFET to charge the battery. When OutputVoltage > 14.0v; pin is high else it is low.
I have also put the deadtime for the MOSFETs.
The problem is that it just doesn't give me 14v at the output instead fluctuates from 6.19v to 7.39v.
controller used- Atmega 32A

```
#define F_CPU 8000000

const float T_DeadTime = 1.00f;
float voltageFeedback=0.0f;
uint8_t duty=0;
```

**MAIN.c**

```
int main(void)
{
    sei();
    _delay_ms(500);
    
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD4)|(1 << DDD5);
    _delay_ms(100);
    
    PWM_Init();
    _delay_ms(500);
    duty=20;
while (1)
    {
        pwm();
        _delay_ms(500);
        
        voltageFeedback=readVoltagefeedback();
        
        if(voltageFeedback<14.0f)
        {
            PORTC&=~(1<<PINC6);
        }
        else if(voltageFeedback>=14.0f)
        {
            PORTC|=1<<PINC6;
        }
}
}
void initiallizePort()
 {
 DDRC |= (1<<PINC6);
 PORTC &= ~(1<<PINC6);
}
```

**pwm functions**

```
 void pwm()
  {
     if(voltageFeedback >= 14.6)
      {
          duty=duty-1;
          if(duty<11)
          {
              duty=11;
          }
          else{
              //do nothing
          }
      }
      else if(voltageFeedback <= 14.0)
      {
          
          duty=duty+1;
          if(duty>=190)
          {
              duty=190;
          }
          else{
              //do nothing
          }
      }
      PWM_mu(duty);
      _delay_ms(1000);
  }
```

**ADC**

```
#define ADC_VOLT_FBK  ADC0
#define ADC0    0x40
#define OPVOLTAGE_FACTOR  0.0537f

float rawData = 0.0f;
int adcResult = 0;


int readADCValue(uint8_t adcNumber)
{
    ADMUX=adcNumber;
    ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADIE) | (1<<ADPS0) | (1<<ADPS1) | (1<<ADPS2);// 
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);//Start Conversion
    sei();
    _delay_ms(5);
    return adcResult;
}
float readVoltagefeedback()
{
    rawData = OPVOLTAGE_FACTOR*readADCValue(ADC_VOLT_FBK);
    return rawData;
}
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    adcResult = ADC;
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);//Start Conversion
}
```

even if the condition is given as 14v yet the pinc6 turns high and low after 10v. The Adc is working fine as I checked the feedback voltage in a serial terminal through UART.

Comment: You should post a schematic diagram of how it's all connected.

Comment: What is `PWM_mu`. Is AREF voltage properly connected?